# How to solve this using linear diophantine equations?

Tags: abstract-algebra, diophantine-equations, linear-diophantine-equations

A trader has a beam balance and two weight weighing *25* grams and *60* grams using the theory **diophantine equations**, shows how he can sell exactly *40* grams of flour, using only these two weights and balance.

I got infinity number of solutions therefore it's not sure, give me a hint to restriction the solution if it is possible

Thank you!!

Comment: I'm sure there are infinitely many solutions.  I don't think the problem was asking you for one solution in particular.

Comment: @lulu Thank you

Comment: Try to write down the equation. Have a look at "solutions of linear Diophantine equations".

Comment: @DietrichBurde I solved it but I have infinity many solution,is there any clue to restriction the solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I see only $4$ possible measures of flour where $F_n$ is flour-weight and one or more $numbers$ are the weights.

$$F_{25}=25\quad F_{40}+25=65\quad F_{65}=65\quad F_{90}=25+65\quad $$

I see no need for diophantine equations. but

$8F+5a=13b$ works if $ F=a=c=5\quad$ or $\quad5f+5a=5b\implies f=8,\space  a=5,\space b=13$.

Is this the sort of thing giving you trouble? Perhaps the equation they are looking for is simply $f+a=b$. Let me/us know what you've tried.

Comment: but there are infinity many numbers of solution in my solution, don't you have more solutions?

Comment: This problem is said to use diophantine equation